# Linearization between two ranges

Tags: linear-transformations, linearization

We are currently trying to solve a problem where the input is range of variables x and y.

y $\in$ {min, max}. 
x $\in$ {0, 255}

min & max are integers of range $\{-2^{32}, 2^{32} \}$

Need to find the linearization factors (M, b, k1, k2) for the given formula below:

$$ y = ( M*x + B * 10^{k1} ) * 10^{k2} $$

Using the computed M, B, k1 and k2 values, we should able to convert x given y and y given x.

Also, it a constraint that M, B, k1 and k2 values are whole numbers and not in the decimal form.

Current understanding:
One can form 2 equations using the ranges but we have four variables in this case.

Can anyone please give some direction to solve this problem?

Reference:
IPMI specification chapter 36.3

Comment: I'm new to this area of computation. Can you please update the tags and question specification if necessary. Please let me know in comments if you need further clarifications.

Comment: What is the y range?  min and max of what?